# LitElement render() not called on quick state updates

Tags: typescript, redux, tensorflow.js, lit-element

I have a problem with updating the visuals on a polymer page. My element looks as follows:

```
import { html, LitElement, property } from 'lit-element';
import { connect } from 'pwa-helpers/connect-mixin.js';

// These are the shared styles needed by this element.
import { SharedStyles } from '../../styles/shared-styles.js';

// This element is connected to the Redux store.
import { store, RootState } from '../../store.js';

class TFJSItem extends connect(store)(LitElement) {
  @property({type: Number})
  private _prediction = 0;

  static styles = SharedStyles;

  protected render() {
    console.log(this._prediction);
    return html`
      <section>
        <h2>TFJS</h2>
        <p>${this._prediction}</p>
      </section>
    `;
  }

  // This is called every time something is updated in the store.
  stateChanged(state: RootState) {
    console.log(state.network!.prediction);
    this._prediction = state.network!.prediction;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('tfjs-item', TFJSItem);
```

I have a script running for 1000 iterations, that sends an action to redux to update the number stored in `network.prediction`. However, the number that is displayed in the elements gets updated only once, after the last state change happened. Since I want this to be a live-running number, however, I want every change to be recorded.
The strange thing is, that the second `console.log()` gets executed for each change, however, render is only called once.

The data comes from a tfjs training process. I want to update the prediction everytime a new iteration has been made:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as d from './data';
import * as m from './model';

import { store } from '../store.js';
import { newPrediction } from '../actions/network.js';

export class Training {
  model: m.Model;
  data: d.Data;
  iterations: number;

  constructor(model: m.Model, data: d.Data) {
    this.model = model;
    this.model.model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
    this.data = data;
    this.iterations = 0;
  }

  start() {
    var this_ = this;
    if (this.iterations < 1000) {
      this.iterate();
    }
  }

  iterate() {
    this.iterations++;
    tf.tidy(() => {
      const prediction = this.model.model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1]) as tf.Tensor) as tf.Tensor<tf.Rank>;
      store.dispatch(newPrediction(prediction));
      this.model.model.trainOnBatch(this.data.xs, this.data.ys);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: are you waiting for some time (setTimeout or equivalent) between sending each action to redux? i know redux can batch state updates so you might only see the last one if they are too close together

Comment: Thank you for this information! I do now wait for 1ms after each iteration as follows:
    `start() {
        var this_ = this;
        if (this.iterations < 1000) {
          this.iterate();
          setTimeout (function() { this_.start(); }, 1);
        }
      }`

Comment: You wanna post this as an answer? Then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Another possible wrinkle: your TFJS trainer should call `await tf.nextFrame()` periodically to yield control, to avoid hanging the UI.  This is generally automated when using `LayersModel.fit()` and `LayersModel.fitDataset()`, but check out the `yieldEvery` argument there to tweak the behavior (https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.fit).

Comment: Ok, I did not expect this to be tensorflow-related. However, I will add the tensorflow code now, since you pointed me this direction. I am not using `model.fit()` since I want to have control over when an iteration is made in the future (stopping/continuing/stepping through iterations).

Answer (score 2):

LitElement batches calls to `render()` (actually the entire update pipeline). It's expected that if you update state a lot in a single task that there will only be one call to `render()`.

Generally rendering faster will not actually show anything more frequently on screen, because both synchronous functions and microtasks block paint, so the browser will only paint the screen after all the updates anyway.